# How to query XML node using ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, extract, elementtree

I have the following example XML tree:

```
<main>
  <section>
     <list key="capital" value="sydney">
        <items>
           <item id="abc-123"></item>
           <item id="abc-345"></item>
        </items>
     </list>
     <list key="capital" value="tokyo">
        <items>
           <item id="def-678"></item>
           <item id="def-901"></item>
        </items>
     </list>
  </section>
</maim>
```

Do you know how to run a query that will extract the "items" node under "list" with key="capital" and value="tokyo" (which should extract item nodes with id="def-678" and id="def-901")?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath expression that `xml.etree` supports (see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)) via `find()` or `findall()` method :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

raw = '''your xml string here'''
root = ET.fromstring(raw)
result = root.findall(".//list[@key='capital'][@value='tokyo']/items/item")
```

**console test output :**

```
>>> for r in result:
...     print ET.tostring(r)
... 
<item id="def-678" />

<item id="def-901" />
```